# Add foreign key on column with different types

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, foreign-keys

I need to add a foreign key constraint on an integer column to reference a text column in another table. Both represent year in 4 digits format, but creating the constraint like

```
ALTER TABLE a 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (year_int) 
    REFERENCES b (cast(year_text as integer));
```

doesn't work and give a syntax error.

So, is it possible without using a view (the b table is already linked by several tables/views)? Or is there a query which can convert all linked tables/views type from text to integer?

Cheers

Comment: Most sensible would be to fix the type of that text column, no?

Comment: Why did you make the year a text in the first place?

Comment: Yes, fixing the type is the best option, it's why I ask if there's a solution to make the change in the referenced tables/views as well. @Cody360c it's an old conception error...

Comment: If you can't change the table definitions, but really, really need that fk, you can get the same functionality using triggers. (Somewhat slower performance perhaps.)

Comment: I can change the defs, but it will be very long to remove/recreate each foreign key to that table (more than 30), and cast each targeted field in these tables/views. For the view it's not a real problem as it can be done with a script like this https://gist.github.com/jwhitehorn/eda46de510ac2804a6124e7258481da7, but I don't find something similar for foreignkey

Comment: A trigger is no replacement for a foreign key constraint (concurrency issues). If you are stuck with `text` for the existing columns, the best solution is probably to define the new column as `text` as well.

Comment: As I said, the text type is an old conception error, now we prefer to have the year field in integer. It's not a problem to have all old tables modified, it's just to have the possibility to convert them programmaticaly